# Serialize and deserialize boost shared pointers

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, boost-serialization

I know there is the chance to use methods created by boost in order to serialize shared pointers, but I've created this:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {

template<class Archive, class T>
inline void serialize(Archive& ar, boost::shared_ptr<T>& b, const unsigned int file_version)
{
    // serialize a string which is the key of the pointer
}

} }
```

Now I'd like to handle the deserialization in the same way. So, I'd like to take the serialized key and get the object in some map.

How can I handle this in the deserialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me you might simply be "optimizing" to avoid duplicate serialized objects.

Boost Serialization already has this feature builtin for (smart) pointers¹: [Object Tracking](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking)

Here's a demo of what it means for your sample:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1aab402e8529485d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct HeyHey {

    std::string name;
    HeyHey(std::string n = "") : name(n) {}

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar & name; }
};

using HeyPtr = std::shared_ptr<HeyHey>;

int main() {

    std::stringstream ss;

    {
        std::vector<HeyPtr> ptrs = { 
            std::make_shared<HeyHey>("one"),
            std::make_shared<HeyHey>("two"),
            std::make_shared<HeyHey>("three"),
            std::make_shared<HeyHey>("four"),
        };

        std::unordered_map<int, HeyPtr> m = {
            { 1, ptrs[0] },
            { 2, ptrs[1] },
            { 3, ptrs[2] },
            { 4, ptrs[3] },
        };

        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
        oa << ptrs << m;
    }

    {
        std::vector<HeyPtr> ptrs;
        std::unordered_map<int, HeyPtr> m;

        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
        ia >> ptrs >> m;

        std::cout << "Deserialized:\n";
        for (auto p : m) {
            std::cout << "Key: " << p.first << " mapped to " << std::quoted(p.second->name) << " at address " << p.second.get() << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << "Vector contains: ";
        for (auto sp: ptrs)
            std::cout << sp.get() << " ";

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

Prints:

```
Deserialized:
Key: 1 mapped to "one" at address 0x25de420
Key: 2 mapped to "two" at address 0x25de450
Key: 3 mapped to "three" at address 0x25de4b0
Key: 4 mapped to "four" at address 0x25de480
Vector contains: 0x25de420 0x25de450 0x25de4b0 0x25de480
```

Note how the map and the vector point to **the same `HeyHey` instances**: the aliases pointers were tracked by the archive and only got (de)serialized once.

¹ and, with some help, for references

Comment: @suse, Thanks for your reply. However this is not exaclty what I meant. My problem is that I have to serialize each T incapsulated inside shared pointer through a string which indentifies each object uniquely. Then, I have to deserialize the object by using the same string. So, since I've the `serialize` function to serialize the object, I need the function `deserialize` in order to handle a particular object in a different way.

Comment: @suse, In any case your answer helps me to understand other better the serialization step. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution just of the top of my head:

How about using an *actual* map (like e.g. [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) to map the raw pointer to an object? Don't forget to serialize the map as well.

Then when de-serializing, first de-serialize the map, and then use the serialized pointer to get the objects from the map.

Comment: It looks a good idea, however I cannot serialize the type of the boost pointer.

Comment: @Surcle Use `get` to get the raw pointer (`T*`), and use as a key in the map and serialize it, perhaps going through `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @Surcle Sure. Any pointers aren't suitable for any kind of _de-/serialization_ in a reasonable manner.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, can you give me an example please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's a pretty misleading statement. Boost Serialization has splendid excellent for pointers all around (Object Tracking and Polymorphism).

Comment: Added my own answer to both demonstrate that pointers are no issue for Boost Serialization, and to answer the probably [XY-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)